# APS The Service is temporarily unavailable

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-model-derivative, autodesk-data-management

I am getting an error when uploading files to the bucket. There does not appear to be a problem with APS in Autodesk Health Dashboard. What could be the problem? Or is there a problem with the servers?

```
{
    "config": {
        "url": "buckets?region=US",
        "method": "get",
        "headers": {
            "Accept": "application/json, text/plain, */*",
            "Authorization": "Bearer mycode",
            "User-Agent": "axios/0.21.4"
        },
        "baseURL": "https://developer.api.autodesk.com/oss/v2/",
        "transformRequest": [
            null
        ],
        "transformResponse": [
            null
        ],
        "timeout": 0,
        "xsrfCookieName": "XSRF-TOKEN",
        "xsrfHeaderName": "X-XSRF-TOKEN",
        "maxContentLength": 9007199254740991,
        "maxBodyLength": 9007199254740991,
        "transitional": {
            "silentJSONParsing": true,
            "forcedJSONParsing": true,
            "clarifyTimeoutError": false
        }
    },
    "data": {
        "fault": {
            "faultstring": "The Service is temporarily unavailable",
            "detail": {
                "errorcode": "messaging.adaptors.http.flow.ServiceUnavailable"
            }
        }
    },
    "headers": {
        "content-type": "application/json",
        "date": "Tue, 23 Jan 2024 12:44:07 GMT",
        "strict-transport-security": "max-age=31536000; includeSubDomains",
        "content-length": "139",
        "connection": "Close"
    },
    "status": 503,
    "statusText": "Service Unavailable"
}
```

I tried to upload files with visual studio code application and nodejs server but I failed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no problem right now, I think it was a temporary server problem.

Comment: yes, we experienced a temporary spike for a short moment on Tuesday. It was running again soon. Sorry for the problem that caused your inconvenience

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).